# Creating a new Data Frame using columns from another

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I need to create a new Data Frame named 'indicators' made up of the columns 'Indicator Name' and 'Indicator Code', delete all duplicated entries, and
set the column 'Indicator Code' as the index of 'indicators'.

Indicators are to be used as the indices 
#Accessing and Indexing of Rows:

```
wdi = pd.DataFrame(Country Name,
                    columns=["Indicator Name", "Indicator Code"],
                     index=Country Name[indicators])
```

> print(wdi.loc[])

Comment: Do you have some reproducible example?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples